# Macro Excel para mover Arriba/Abajo el contenido de una celda

Tags: excel, vba, macros, microsoft-office, celdas

Hola buen día soy nuevo en este tema de Macros con Excel y me gustaria crear un "tipo" de botones que me permita "Cortar" el contenido de una celda (Nombre, Edad) cada vez que presione el boton "Arriba o Abajo" segun sea el caso.

Actualizacion 2:
Ya esta el codigo para subir o bajar, solo que todavia no es funcional al 100% ya que no me corta y sube/baja el texto bien.

Actualizando:

```
    Sub RowsUp() 'Boton Subir
    Dim b As Object, cs As Integer
    Set b = ActiveSheet.Buttons(Application.Caller)
    With b.TopLeftCell
      cs = .Row
      If cs <= 1 Then Exit Sub
      Rows(cs).Select
      Selection.Cut
      Selection.Offset(.Rows.Count - 2).Insert
      .Select
    End With
End Sub

Sub RowsDown() 'Boton Bajar   
    Dim b As Object, cs As Integer
    Set b = ActiveSheet.Buttons(Application.Caller)
    With b.TopLeftCell
      cs = .Row
      If cs <= 1 Then Exit Sub
      Rows(cs).Select
      Selection.Cut
      Selection.Offset(.Rows.Count + 1).Insert
      .Select
    End With
End Sub
```

[image: Ejemplo: Nom4, moverlo/cortarlo hacia arriba o abajo cada vez que pulso un boton, pero que me respete el texto donde se va a mover Nom4, pero no se si es posible hacerlo en excel; ¿Alguna sugerencia para que comience a crear el codigo con VB? Muchas gracias por su orientacion en este tema que es nuevo para mi :)]

Comment: Ejemplo: Nom4 y su Edad moverlo/cortarlo hacia arriba o abajo cada vez que pulso un boton, pero que me respete el texto donde se va a mover Nom4 y la Edad, pero no se si es posible hacerlo en excel; ¿Alguna sugerencia para que comience a crear el codigo con VB? Muchas gracias por su orientacion en este tema que es nuevo para mi :)

Comment: He encontrado esta propiedad que me permite:

Sub arriba() 'Subir el cursor
ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Select
End Sub

Sub abajo()
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
End Sub

continuare investigando como mover el contenido "tipo cortar texto" y subirlo o bajarlo en la lista

Comment: Range("A1").Cut Range("B1") 
'Para cortar y pegar el contenido de A1 a B1

Comment: Cuando hagas actualizaciones de tu pregunta original, **edita** tu primer post, no lo pongas en comentarios, porque dificulta mucho la lectura, por favor.

Answer (score 2):

Podrías simplificar el código y jugar con los valores:

```
Sub ARRIBA()
If ActiveCell.Row < 3 Then Exit Sub
Dim MiNombre As String
Dim MiEdad As Long

'guardamos datos originales de la celda activa
MiNombre = Range("A" & ActiveCell.Row).Value
MiEdad = Range("B" & ActiveCell.Row).Value

'ponemos los de la celda superior en la activa
Range("A" & ActiveCell.Row).Value = Range("A" & ActiveCell.Row - 1).Value
Range("B" & ActiveCell.Row).Value = Range("B" & ActiveCell.Row - 1).Value

'ponemos en fila superior los de la celda activa
'que estñan guardados en las variables

Range("A" & ActiveCell.Row - 1).Value = MiNombre
Range("B" & ActiveCell.Row - 1).Value = MiEdad

End Sub

Sub ABAJO()
If ActiveCell.Row > Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row Then Exit Sub
Dim MiNombre As String
Dim MiEdad As Long

'guardamos datos originales de la celda activa
MiNombre = Range("A" & ActiveCell.Row).Value
MiEdad = Range("B" & ActiveCell.Row).Value

'ponemos los de la celda inferior en la activa
Range("A" & ActiveCell.Row).Value = Range("A" & ActiveCell.Row + 1).Value
Range("B" & ActiveCell.Row).Value = Range("B" & ActiveCell.Row + 1).Value

'ponemos en fila superior los de la celda activa
'que estñan guardados en las variables

Range("A" & ActiveCell.Row + 1).Value = MiNombre
Range("B" & ActiveCell.Row + 1).Value = MiEdad

End Sub
```

El código ARRIBA intercambia los datos de tu selección activa con la fila superior.
El código ABAJO intercambia los datos de tu selección activa con fila inferior.

Un ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: excelente, es cierto es mas simplificado con el codigo que compartes y funciona sin problemas.... muchas gracias por el aporte @Esei

Comment: Ahora estoy jugando con la propiedad Selection.EntireRow.Select para que al momento de mover Arriba/Abajo el texto, seleccione esa celda que se movio y la deje seleccionada hasta que la deje en el lugar deseado de la lista

Comment: agregue dos lineas de codigo extras para seleccionar toda la fila donde se encuentra el texto a mover Arriba/Abajo, lo deje como comentarios extras al codigo que simplificaste